# Use non-standard key ("ö") in emacs evil mode for key-chord-define

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I use the following mapping to get from evil insert mode into normal mode:

```
(key-chord-define evil-insert-state-map "jj" 'evil-normal-state)
```

This works fine. However, I would like to use the key "ö" on my German keyboard for it:

```
(key-chord-define evil-insert-state-map "öö" 'evil-normal-state)
```

This results in the following error message at startup: "error: Key-chord keys must have two element".

I guess I might have to escape the special character in some way; however, I could not find out how. Any suggestions?

Comment: That error suggests that `"öö"` has a length other than two, which is not the case on my Emacs... Could you try evaluating `(length "öö")`, copying the string in your `key-chord-define`, to see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is already in the comments of the key-chord-define question; we cannot use non-asccii characters like "ö" for now:

"Define in KEYMAP, a key-chord of the two keys in KEYS starting a COMMAND.
\nKEYS can be a string or a vector of two elements. Currently only elements
that corresponds to ascii codes in the range 32 to 126 can be used.
\nCOMMAND can be an interactive function, a string, or nil.
If COMMAND is nil, the key-chord is removed."

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/key-chord.el